# Adding a member variable to inherited class in Python

Tags: python, oop

Here is something I tried in Python (2.7.9) shell (IDLE on Windows):

```
>>> class A:
    def bob(self, x):
        self.val = x*x
```

followed by:

```
>>> class B(A):
        def bob(self,x):
            flow = x*x*x
            A.bob(self, x)
```

and then:

```
>>> y = B()
>>> y.bob(4)
>>> y.val
16
>>> y.flow

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#52>", line 1, in <module>
    y.flow
AttributeError: B instance has no attribute 'flow'
```

Question is, why is the method flow() undefined ? Looking around, I got the impression that perhaps the member variable might have to be initialized in **init**() during object construction phase, but that didn't help either.

Comment: By the way, the question you literally wrote is "why is the method flow() undefined". What it's complaining about is that the _attribute_ `flow` doesn't exist. And I'm pretty sure you expected a normal data attribute (a variable referring to the number 64), not a method there, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flow` on its own is just a local variable, that lives as long as this method and then goes away.

`self.flow` is an instance variable. That's what you wanted.

(If you're coming from another language like C++ that has an implicit `this`/`self` for members... Python doesn't have that. [Guido explains why](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html), even with some clever ideas that make the historical reasons no longer relevant, Python still doesn't have that, and probably never will.)

---

As a side note, in Python 2.7, always use `class A(object):`, not `class A:`. Otherwise, you're creating old-style classes. That doesn't make a difference in this case, but in cases where it *does* make a difference, you always want the new behavior.*

---

> Looking around, I got the impression that perhaps the member variable might have to be initialized in init() during object construction phase, but that didn't help either.

Well, first, it's `__init__`; a method just called `init` won't get called during object construction.

Anyway, usually you *want* to create all your attributes in `__init__`. (That's one easy way to guarantee that all instances of your type will have those members—unless you `del` them, of course…) But there's nothing *requiring* you to. In Python, you can add and delete attributes to an object at any time.**

---

<sub>* There are some cases where arguably you don't, but if you don't already know those cases and how to evaluated those arguments, they don't apply to you.</sub>

<sub>** Unless the class prevents you from doing so. Many builtin types do; you can do something similar yourself with `__slots__`; or you can even write a custom `__setattr__` method that does anything you want.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

you're not assigning flow to the class instance

```
class B(A):
    def bob(self,x):
        flow = x*x*x  # should be self.flow
        A.bob(self, x)
```

[more on scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)